# Why do I not need 3 levels of braces for initializing 3 levels of arrays?

Tags: c++, struct, nested, uniform-initialization

I came across to this example

```
struct sct
{
    int t[2];
};

struct str
{
    sct t[2];
};

int main()
{
    str t[2] = { {0, 2, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 7} }; //Who does this work?

    cout << t[1].t[0].t[1] << t[0].t[1].t[0];     

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs fine. It gives the output `34`

I expected the syntax for initialization would be:

```
str t[2] = {  { {0, 2},{4, 6} }, { {1, 3},{5, 7} }   };
```

Instead of

```
 { {0, 2, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 7} };
```

But this gave:

```
In function 'int main()':
error: too many initializers for 'str'
```

Can someone explain why?

This is a picture to illustrate the way I see this:
[image]

### How should i think when it comes to initializing nested structs?

Comment: When asking questions involving build errors, please always include the actual errors you get, copy-pasted as text in full and complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a simple typo but the situation is complex enough to tackle it step by step.

First let me show the solution that seems to work:

```
int main()
{
    str t[2] = { { { {0, 2}, {4, 6} } }, { { {1, 3}, {5, 7} } } };
    cout << t[1].t[0].t[1] << t[0].t[1].t[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So we have an array of `str` that holds an array of `sct`.

Let's start with the latter. You initialize an array of `sct` with something like this:

```
sct x[2] = { {0, 1}, {2, 3} };
```

Now for a single instance of `str` you could go with

```
str y = { { {0, 2}, {4, 6} } };
```

What remains for `str t[2]` is to arrange two copies of `str` initializing expressions inside curly brackets:

```
str t[2] = { { { {0, 2}, {4, 6} } }, { { {1, 3}, {5, 7} } } };
```

---

**Edited:** On the first reading I misunderstood the question. After the post was updated it became clear that the question is on why it is possible to shed two pair of braces but shedding just one pair results in a syntax error.

To understand how the parser is interpreting the code you might like to look at the parse tree. You can make gcc dump trees at several stages of the parser with `-fdump-tree-...` options. Here `-fdump-tree-original` may be useful.

To avoid additional confusion let's make sure the elements of the structures have different names:

```
struct sct
{
    int a[2];
};

struct str
{
    sct b[2];
};
```

Here is the output I got with GCC 7.5 from

```
>>>> CODE:
str t[2] = { { 0, 2, 4, 6 }, { 1, 3, 5, 7 } };
>>>> tree enabled by -tree-original
struct str t[2] = {{.b={{.a={0, 2}}, {.a={4, 6}}}}, {.b={{.a={1, 3}}, {.a={5, 7}}}}};
```

You can see that the compiler adds implicit brackets around the initializing expressions for each structure and around the initializing expressions for each named field.

Now consider the expression that fails to compile:

```
str t[2] = {  { {0, 2},{4, 6} }, { {1, 3},{5, 7} }   };
```

A the upper level the tree for this expression would be

```
/*Step 1: */ struct str t[2] = { {.b={0, 2}, {4, 6} }, {.b={1, 3}, {5, 7} } };
```

But as b is an array of `sct`, we try to initialize that with `{0,2}` getting

```
sct b[2] = {0, 2};
```

This expands to

```
struct sct b[2] = {{.a={0, 2} }};
```

This is valid C++ since the first element of the array is initialized explicitly and the second element is initialized implicitly with zeros.

With this knowledge we get the following tree

```
/*Step 2: */ struct str t[2] = { {.b={{.a={0, 2} }}, {4, 6} }, {.b={{.a={1, 3} }}, {5, 7} } };
```

Now we are left with the following:

```
 struct str z = { { { {0,2} }, { {0,0} } }, {4, 6} };
```

And the compiler rightfully complains:

```
 error: too many initializers for ‘str’
```

---

As a final check consider the following declaration

```
 struct sxc
 {
     sct b[2];
     int c[2];
 }

 struct sxc z = { {0,2} , {4, 6} };
```

This compiles and result in the following structure:

```
 { .b = { { .a={0,2} }, { .a={0,0} } }, .c={4, 6} }
```

Comment: Ok, but how does it comes that you are allowed to simply enumerate separated by comma the values as `str t[2] = { {0, 2, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 7} }`. I see that the compiler assumes them in order.  From the last line of you answer, how would you modify to get to this one `{ {0, 2, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 7} }`?

Comment: I mean which would be the reason you can get rid of some curly brackets?

Comment: You may misunderstand the intent of the question @Dimitri. This code compiles and runs fine. I think she's asking "doesn't it need another set of braces (`{ }`)?"

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu Indeed I realize that I missed the intention of your original post, thank you for the clarification. I have updated the answer with an attempt to reconstruct the logic of the compiler.

Comment: what is meant by `.a` and `.b`? The immediately curly bracket behind `.` is added by the compiler ?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu The dot notation is used by the compiler to annotate the parse tree. In order to make things easier to read I renamed `sct.t` and `str.t` to `sct.a` and `str.b` respectively. That is where `.a` and `.b` come from.